# Specific Questions About useReducer + Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Specific Questions About useReducer + Context

Hello,

I am practicing different ways of passing data around in React, however there are a few things that still evade me even after hours of scouring examples and documentation. Consider the following questions in the context of the code that follows (a very small sandbox app I am learning wtih):

---

0) From what I understand, I need access to the dispatch method in order to update GlobalContext via the reducer in context.tsx. Furthermore, I shoule be able to access that same dispatch method in any component via the useContext method. I just don't know how to get at the dispatch method. from a component who is importing GlobalContext. When I try (as seen in header.tsx), there is an error that says "property dispatch doesn't exist on type 'IGlobalState'". IGlobalState is the type of the state object itself (which lives in context.tsx), not the returned result of createContext, but this error seems to think otherwise? Not sure what is wrong here.

---

1) In context.tsx, I was forced by VSCode to typecast { state, dispatch } to any, since passing them in wrapped in {} into the value prop of GlobalContext.Provider doesn't work for some reason? Every tutorial and example online for react/ts doesn't have this workaround. Why does  not work like it seems to so easily for everyone else? Using 'any' kind of defeats the purpose of typescript...

---

2) In loader.tsx, I understand exactly how useContext is being used; it is allowing me to access the properties of the global state with the syntax "globalContext.isLoading", for example. However, in examples [such as this](https://blog.logrocket.com/use-hooks-and-context-not-react-and-redux/), they seem to just pull the dispatch method right out of the useContext return value, which doesn't make sense to me. Wouldn't useContext just return the current state in object form? Here is the specific snipped found in the link above that I am talking about:

```
import { GlobalContext } from "Components/Context"; // Assume this points to context.tsx

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const globalState = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const { dispatch } = globalState;

  dispatch({ type: '' }) // Empty example
};
```

You can see that I ddi the same thing in header.js, but it didn't work. So exactly how does it work and how is it supposed to work? I have been struggling trying to understand how the article's author was able to access the dispatch function with those lines of code. Even with the same setup, it still throws as error which I understnad but I don't understand why i am getting it (see questino 0).

From what I understand, I should have access to the dispatch method since I wrapped the entire app in the GlobalContext.Provider in the root index.tsx. I also suppposedly passed in the state and dispatch as an object into the value props in GlobalStateProvider, albeit though a hacky way that I don't understand (see question #1 above).

I am sure the answer is not far away but I would appreciate anyone who could enlighted me! THANK YOU for any help, React + Typescript are so awesome! I absolutely love the dev/learning experience so far. Here is the app code:

---

**index.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { GlobalStateProvider } from "Components/Context";
import { App } from "Components/App";

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <GlobalStateProvider>
      <App />
    </GlobalStateProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

**app.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Loader } from "Components/Loader";
import { Header } from "Components/Header";
import "Assets/styles.scss";

export const App = () => {
    return(
        <div className="app">
            <Loader />
            <Header />
        </div>
    );
};
```

---

**header.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { globalActions, GlobalContext } from "Components/Context";
import * as API from "Components/API";
import $ from "jquery";

export const Header = () => {
  const globalState = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const { dispatch } = globalState; // <-- QUESTION_0
    const handleKeyPress = async (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const searchbarInput: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $("input[name='searchbarInput']");
    const header: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $(".header");
    if (
      searchbarInput.val() &&
      (header.is(":hover") || searchbarInput.is(":focus")) &&
      event.key === "Enter"
    ) {
      searchbarInput.blur();

      dispatch({ type: globalActions.load });

      // DO STUFF HERE...
    }
  };

  return(
    <div className="header">
      <div className="searchbar">
        <input className="input" name="searchbarInput" onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} placeholder="Search..." type="text" />
        <svg>
          ... // searchbar icon
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

**context.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

interface IGlobalActions {
    type: string;
    payload?: Array<string> | object | string;
};

interface IGlobalState {
  isLoading: boolean;
};

const globalActions = {
    load: "START_LOADING",
};

const initialState: IGlobalState = {
  isLoading: false,
};

const GlobalContext = createContext<IGlobalState>(initialState);
const { Provider } = GlobalContext;

const reducer = (state: IGlobalState, action: IGlobalActions) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case globalActions.load:
            return { isLoading: true };
        default:
            throw new Error("Invalid action type (StateProvider)");
    };
};

const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Trigger loading animation
        if (state.isLoading) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch({ 
                    type: globalActions.load
                });
            }, 2000)
        }
    },
    [state.isLoading]);

  return (
        <Provider value={{ state, dispatch } as any}> // <-- QUESTION_1
            {children}
        </Provider>
    );
};

export { globalActions, GlobalContext, GlobalStateProvider };
```

---

**loader.tsx**

```
import React, { useContext }  from "react";
import * as classnames from "classnames";
import { GlobalContext } from "Components/Context";

export const Loader = () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const classNames = classnames({"loader": true}, {"is-loading": globalContext.isLoading});
  const loadingAnimation = "https://link/to/loading/animation";

  return (
    <div className={classNames} >
      <img className="image" src={loadingAnimation} alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For any future googlers:

The answer here was to specifically give a type to the returned value of the switch statement. That type should be the same one that defines the shape of your state. Here is the working context.tsx file for reference:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

type Action = {
    type: string;
    payload?: Array<string> | object | string;
};

type State = {
    isLoading: boolean,
};

type Dispatch = (action: Action) => void;
type GlobalProviderProps = {children: React.ReactNode};

const GlobalStateContext = createContext<State | undefined>(undefined)
const GlobalDispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch | undefined>(undefined);

const initialState: State = {
    isLoading: false,
};

const globalReducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SHOW_LOADER":
            const newState: State = {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            };
            return newState;
        default:
            throw new Error("Invalid action type (StateProvider)");
    };
};

const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }: GlobalProviderProps) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(globalReducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (state.isLoading) {
            console.log("state.isLoading = true");
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch({ 
                    type: "SHOW_LOADER"
                });
            }, 2000)
        }
    },
    [state.isLoading]);

  return (
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    );
};

const useGlobalState = () => {
  const context = useContext(GlobalStateContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useGlobalState must be used within a GlobalStateProvider')
  }
  return context;
};

const useGlobalDispatch = () => {
  const context = useContext(GlobalDispatchContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useGlobalDispatch must be used within a GlobalStateProvider')
  }
  return context;
};

export { useGlobalState, useGlobalDispatch, GlobalStateProvider };
```